How to Integrate TDLib into Node.js and Clarify Its API with Detailed Documentation
I want to use TDLib in Node.js (not the API related to bots). According to the documentation, it should have a JSON format, but I couldn't find how to use it and its relevant addresses. Also, I'm looking for an example or documentation that clearly explains the request and response for each method and address, similar to Swagger
I have checked all available packages, but each had its own issues. I prefer to work without a package and directly.
